How can I know if NCCL is installed?
Very simple question. I have access to a multi-node machine and I have to do some NCCL tests.
In the readme it says

If CUDA is not installed in /usr/local/cuda, you may specify
CUDA_HOME. Similarly, if NCCL is not installed in /usr, you may
specify NCCL_HOME.

I can see that CUDA is installed but (and here it comes my question)
how can I know if NCCL is installed? and where?

Other info
I have done
find /usr -name "libnccl.so*" 2>/dev/null

and I found this file. However when I di
find /usr -name "nccl.h" 2>/dev/null

it was not found.  Obviously I could not build even the simplest
#include <stdio.h>
#include <nccl.h>

int main() {
    printf("NCCL version: %d\n", NCCL_VERSION_CODE);
    return 0;
}

(Btw, I think the OS is CentOS)
